# Java VM Path Selection for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am installing Tomcat for first time and was wondering what is the best path to give to it for Java Path?  Should I point to to JRE? to bin? to JDK?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tomcat requires the JDK.  Set the path to your `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` where the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable points to your JDK.

EDIT:

From Apache's site, to expand on the environment variable for Windows:

> **Set** `JAVA_HOME`. 
>   Set this environment variable to point at the top-level
>   of your Java installation directory (e.g., C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21).

Comment: Tomcat does *not* require the JDK. That hasn't been true for a long, long time. It even says in the screenshot that it's looking for a JRE, not a JDK (though the JDK is a perfectly fine choice for JRE).

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I'm not sure where you see that, from Apache's own website on installation (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/installation.html), it says it _depends_ on the JDK (first on the list.)

EDIT: I just saw your answer and followed your link--looks like they have conflicting statements; go figure.  At any rate, it seems to be suggested to use the JDK over the JRE, although I guess from your link may not be _technically_ required.

Comment: I assure you @OnResolve, Tomcat does not require a JDK. Tomcat comes bundled with the Eclipse JDT compiler for JSP compilation, which was the only reason Tomcat ever needed a JDK and not a JRE. I will amend the documentation to reflect reality.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz You've missed my point; I've conceded that Tomcat  may not _require_ the JDK but rather that Apache recommends the JDK over the JRE.

Comment: I certainly see your point, but you are reading the "application development" section of the Tomcat user's guide. You can deploy webapps without a JDK but if you want to write your own software, you are going to have to figure out how to compile it. They also mention CVS on that same page, and Tomcat obviously does not require CVS.

Answer (score 4):

Try reading Tomcat's [installer instructions](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html#Windows):

> The installer will provide a default JRE to use to run the service. The installer uses the registry to determine the base path of a Java 6 or later JRE, including the JRE installed as part of the full JDK. When running on a 64-bit operating system, the installer will first look for a 64-bit JRE and only look for a 32-bit JRE if a 64-bit JRE is not found. It is not mandatory to use the default JRE detected by the installer. Any installed Java 6 or later JRE (32-bit or 64-bit) may be used.

If you don't like the auto-detected value, you can enter your own. In your case, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01` should be what you enter. If that does not work, you may have to add `\jre` to the end of that path (just like in the example).